# HTML, CSS & Vertical text margins

Tags: html, css, text, margins

This is probably basic stuff, so if there's some kind of online reference for how html text & margins work, please just throw me a link.

Anyway, I'm having some trouble defining exact margins for text. Below is an example of an image, a div containing text below it and more text below the div. Other margins are set to 0, and margins for the div is 10px top & bottom, 0 left & right. For reasons unknown to me, it turns out 16px top, 14px bottom. I could just compensate the error with the margin definitions, but I would actually like to know what's going on instead of treating the symptoms.

```
<img src="images/temp/img.png" />
<div><p>Testing</p></div>
<h2>Siirry</h2>
```

And style for the div is

```
div {
    color:#f00;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:9px;
    line-height:9px;
    height:9px;
    margin:10px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Example image:

[image: Example]

EDIT:

More info since my point didn't apparently come out very clearly:
The margin is 10px according to tools such as Firebug. That is not what I'm asking. However because of the way the fonts are rendered, the box of the text is actually larger than the actual size of the text. This causes the VISUAL margin to be larger than the defined margin (which you can verify by measuring it in Photoshop or simnilar software). I'm looking for information about the relation between text's box size and actual size, so I can define margins properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the font doesn't use the entire height. A better (though maybe not perfect) indication would be to select the text and check the margins between the black border and the highlighted rectangle. And that goes for the text below 'testing' too. It will occupy part of those 14px.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant with my question. I wanted to understand the basics behind that so that I could more robustly set exact margins for texts containing different font sizes.

Comment: You're already setting exact margins. The space between the letter and the top of the line cannot be determined in CSS since this is a property of the font you are using, and can even vary between versions of the font, not to mention different characters within the same font! You should design for line height, not font. If, for a specific reason, you need the exact pixels to be measured from the letter, you should indeed measure that distance in a drawing tool and make according adjustments in your CSS. But I think that should be an exception.

Comment: In that case, you should measure the distance between the top of the letter and the top of the line (which you can see best if the text is selected). Then, subtract the amount of pixels you measured from the margin you want to have. So, if the distance from the top of 'H' to the top of the selection is 3px, and you want the margin to be 10px, you should set the margin to 7px. If this is a margin between two lines, you should do a similar measurement from the bottom of 'j' to the bottom of the selection. Then, subtract both found values from the original 10px to get the actual margin you need.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I guess I'll have to go with the manual method then.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. Could you recreate the problematic situation with http://jsfiddle.net/ to share it with us?

However there are problems with your CSS. You shouldn't specify the 9px height on the div (it's at least 20px high due to the margins). Specifying the line height has nothing to do with the size of the font but with the space between two lines of text (not your case).

Last thing: what did you use to measure the margins (16 & 14px)? An image editor? You should use something like Firebug or chrome developper tools.

Comment: Yes, the margin is 10px according to firebug etc. I used Photoshop to measure it, because I need the space between the exact top of the text and image to be exactly 10px, not whatever the browser thinks is 10px. The box of the text is usually larger than the actual size of the character.

Answer (score 0):

[Looks fine to me](http://jsfiddle.net/fcHZN/1/)

Here, I've added some backgrounds so you can see where the boxes go: http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/fcHZN/3/

There's definitely a 10px gap between the boxes. Looks like your extra spacing is coming from your image or the `Siirry` text, neither of which we have CSS for.

Comment: If you take a screenshot of that and compare the spaces between texts and boxes in Photoshop, you'll see that the space in fact is not 10px.